# Anyone have missing reference list - Kerber "Representations . . . I"

Tags: gr.group-theory

My copy of Kerber's Representations of Permutation Groups I is missing the pages containing the references.  Anybody got a copy that shows such?

Answer (score 2):

http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0067943 has freely downloadable pdf Back Matters which is exactly what you need.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you Dima!  Yes, indeed, exactly what I needed.  Wonderful!